# iOS Libcurl Proxy C++

Tags: ios, xcode, proxy, libcurl

We are having difficulties getting through a proxy on iPad connected to mobile hot spot network provided. We tried to get system current proxy settings based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588923/ios-get-proxy-settings) post, however it retrieves proxy settings only if they are set in iPad settings ->Wi-Fi-> information label on currently connected network -> HTTP proxy ->Manual. Meaning we are unable to get through the proxy server set by (probably) mobile internet provider (the proxy settings are not visible on the iPad settings).

Has anybody experienced the same issue, how did you deal with it?
Another question is, if there is any way of figuring out the proxy username and password from the proxy settings (I presume no because of security reasons), or you just have to know these settings and pass it down to an app as a configuration?
Thanks in advance.

curl code not working with mobile hot spot proxy:

```
void TestCurl(std::string ProxyName, std::string proxyPort){        

    CURL *curl;
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    curl = curl_easy_init();

    if(curl) {
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://someURLaddress.php");
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PORT, 80);
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0)" );
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10 );
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &writeCallback);
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, EncryptedMessage.c_str());
      curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1 );
      curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1 );

      std::string ProxyServerSettings = ProxyName + ":" + proxyPort;
      curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, ProxyServerSettings.c_str());
    }
    else{
    ...
    }
    ...//curl cleanup etc
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it retrieves proxy settings only if they are set in iPad settings

If you refer to Settings > Wi-Fi > (info) -> HTTP Proxy you have 3 possibilities:

1. there is no HTTP proxy configured,
2. there is an HTTP proxy manually configured,
3. there is an HTTP proxy automatically configured with a [PAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config) file URL (a.k.a Proxy Auto-Config)

Both `CFNetworkCopySystemProxySettings` and `CFNetworkCopyProxiesForURL` API-s allow you to detect the corresponding configuration.

In particular, you can do something like that (ARC based code):

```
+ (NSDictionary *)detectProxySettings {
  NSDictionary *settings = nil;
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com"];
  NSURL *PAC = nil;

  NSDictionary *system = (NSDictionary *) CFBridgingRelease(CFNetworkCopySystemProxySettings());
  NSArray *proxies = (NSArray *) CFBridgingRelease(CFNetworkCopyProxiesForURL((__bridge CFURLRef) url, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef) system));

  if (![proxies count])
    return nil; // case (1)

  settings = [proxies objectAtIndex:0];

  PAC = [settings objectForKey:(NSString *) kCFProxyAutoConfigurationURLKey];

  if (PAC != nil) {
    // case (3)
    // ...
  }
  // else: case (2)

  return settings;
}
```

> [is] there any way of figuring out the proxy username and password from the proxy settings

You cannot read the password (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13576522/monotouch-auto-proxy-network-credentials-not-working/13693988#13693988) for more details).

That being said, thanks to the above `system` dictionary you can:

- check if the proxy is authenticated: check the `@"HTTPProxyAuthenticated"` key on `system`. If it exists, the value is a boolean (`NSNumber`) indicating whether or not the proxy is authentified,
- get the username if the proxy is authenticated: check the `@"HTTPProxyUsername"` key on `system`. If it exists, the value is a string (`NSString`) containing the username.

To sum up: if the proxy is authenticated, there is **NO** way to automatically retrieve the password. In such a case, you should implement your own UI to ask the end user to type in the proxy password for the corresponding username (e.g with a `UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput`).

Comment: thank you very much for the reply, In the meantime I came across very similar solution to this, except I wasn't sure how to get the PAC file configuration. I was expecting that there's no way of getting the credentials, only if manually typing them in, so the fact there is no possibility to access just made me sure not to dig deep into it. Thank you

Comment: Great! I've not described the PAC part in details. Usually what is done is getting the PAC file content (`stringWithContentsOfURL:usedEncoding:error` from `NSString` is handy in such a case) and then using `CFNetworkCopyProxiesForAutoConfigurationScript` to get the proxies.